# C++ - variadic template partial specialization

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, specialization

Let's have a simple snippet:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
struct A {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "A"; }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct A<T, double, Args...> {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "B"; }
};

template<class T, class B, class... Args>
struct A<T, B, double, Args...> {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "C"; }
};
```

Which i can use in this way:

```
int main() {
    A<int, int, int> a;
    A<int, double, int> b;
    A<int, int, double> c;
    a(); b(); c();
    return 0;
}
```

It properly returns `"ABC"`. But when i declare `A<int, double, double> d;` i get obviously compile time error `ambiguous class template instantiation for struct A<int, double, double>`.

**The question is:** can i do some trick (probably using SFINAE) to take into account the second template argument as it would have a higher priority and specialization returning B would be used? (Ignoring type `double` on third position)

NOTE: types `double` and `int` are used to make example simpler, i will use type traits. And therefore i would like to avoid following specialization as a solution:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
struct A<T, double, double, Args...> {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "D"; }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, you can use SFINAE to not consider the `C` specialization if the second template argument is `double`:

```
template<typename, class T, class... Args>
struct A_impl {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "A"; }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct A_impl<void, T, double, Args...> {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "B"; }
};

template<class T, class B, class... Args>
struct A_impl<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<B,double>::value>::type,
         T, B, double, Args...> {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "C"; }
};

template<class T,class... Args>
using A = A_impl<void,T,Args...>;
```